# runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x603000000040 overflowed to 0x603000000034 (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, runtime-error, deque

I was solving the [Sliding Window Maximum](https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-window-maximum/) problem but I'm receiving the following error on Leetcode but it's working on my local compiler [VSCode]

> Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x603000000040 overflowed to 0x603000000034 (stl_vector.h)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

Here's the code:

```
#include <deque>

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> maxSlidingWindow(vector<int>& A, int k) {
        
        int _max = INT_MIN;
        vector<int> ans;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        {
            _max = max(_max, A[i]);
        }
        if (k == A.size()){
            return {_max};
        }
        
        ans.push_back(_max);
        deque<int> dq;
        dq.push_back(_max);

        for (int i = k; i < A.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (dq.empty())
            {
                dq.push_back(i);
                _max = A[i];
            }
            else
            {
                while (!dq.empty() && A[dq.front()] < A[i])
                {
                    dq.pop_front();
                }
                if (dq.empty())
                {
                    _max = A[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    _max = max(_max, A[i]);
                }
                dq.push_front(A[i]);
                ans.push_back(_max);
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the test data?

Comment: your error message has a line number - which line is that in this code?

Comment: Also, VSCode is not a compiler.  It is a code editor that allows you to run a compiler.  That compiler can be g++, Visual C++, clang, etc. -- you should be aware of the tools you're using as knowing the compiler helps in determining why the program "works" (when it really doesn't).

Comment: Your code is not a [mcve].  Here is [an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b43420498f216a5d) of what your post should look like, including a `main()` that calls the function with test data.

Comment: It probably tries to test your program against k < 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like problem is here: `A[dq.front()] < A[i];`

As I see during runtime `dq.front()` takes the value of `-3` which is not fine, due it is negative index. Actual crash is here `A[dq.front()]`. So there is a programming error in your code.

Also looks like you make the push of wrong index here: `dq.push_front(A[i])`, which means that input does have negative values, which you didn't expect.

And probably you wanted to write `dq.push_front(i)` instead of `dq.push_front(A[i])`.

Fixed program looks like this for you:

```cpp
#include <deque>

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> maxSlidingWindow(vector<int>& A, int k) {
        
        int _max = INT_MIN;
        vector<int> ans;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        {
            _max = max(_max, A[i]);
        }
        if (k == A.size()){
            return {_max};
        }
        
        ans.push_back(_max);
        deque<int> dq;
        dq.push_back(_max);

        for (int i = k; i < A.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (dq.empty())
            {
                dq.push_back(i);
                _max = A[i];
            }
            else
            {
                while (!dq.empty() && A[dq.front()] < A[i])
                {
                    dq.pop_front();
                }
                if (dq.empty())
                {
                    _max = A[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    _max = max(_max, A[i]);
                }
                dq.push_front(i);
                ans.push_back(_max);
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting same error, i made sure that no negative value is being pushed into the queue.

```
Code:
class Solution {
public:
    int dx[4] = {-1, 0, 1, 0};
    int dy[4] = {0, 1, 0, -1};

    bool safe(vector<vector<int>>& grid, int x, int y){
        return (x >= 0 && x < grid.size(), y >= 0 && y < grid[0].size());
    }

    void dfs(vector<vector<int>>& grid, int x, int y, 
    queue<pair<int, int>> &q){
        grid[x][y] = 2;
        for(int z = 0; z < 4; z++){
            int r = x + dx[z];
            int c = y + dy[z];
            if(safe(grid, r, c)){
                if(grid[r][c] == 1) {
                    q.push({r, c});
                    dfs(grid, r, c, q);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int bfs(vector<vector<int>>& grid, 
    queue<pair<int, int>> &q){
        int dist = 0, min_dist = INT_MAX;
        
        while(!q.empty()){
            int s = q.size();
            while(s-- > 0){
                pair<int, int> temp;
                temp = q.front();
                q.pop();
                for(int z = 0; z < 4; z++){
                    int r = temp.first + dx[z];
                    int c = temp.second + dy[z];

                    if(safe(grid, r, c)){
                        if(grid[r][c] == 1) min_dist = min(min_dist, dist);
                        grid[r][c] = 2;
                        q.push({r, c});
                    }
                }
            }
            dist++;
        }
        return min_dist;
    }

    int shortestBridge(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        //int n = grid.size();
        bool flag = false;
        //vector<vector<bool>> vis(n, vector<bool>(n, false));
        queue<pair<int, int>> q;
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[0].size(); j++){
                if(grid[i][j] == 1){
                    q.push({i, j});
                    dfs(grid, i, j, q);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == true) break;
        }
        return bfs(grid, q);
    }
};
```

Question link: https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-bridge/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35180436)

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at memory addresses you see that you have (negative) overflow of 12 bytes:

```
Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x603000000040 overflowed to 0x603000000034 (stl_vector.h)
```

Considering that vector elements are integers with `sizeof` 4 bytes, conclusion is that somewhere you have accessing element with negative index -3